目 for days, months etc
I know how to count other things(for example, 一台目の車 / 一つ目の車. btw, are they both correct, my examples?). How do I use count 目 with days, months and years? For example, I want to say: "From the beginning of my employment on the second month/second day/second week I will need to quit my new job."
新しい仕事をもらってから、二日目に/二ヶ月めに/二週目に(idk how to write it correctly so i asking:D)　辞めます
Is this correct?

What are you trying to say with 一台目?   The expression 一台目の車 is not how you say "one car".  When you append 目 to a counter, you're naming an ordinal: first, second, third, fourth,...  By 一台目の車 , do you mean "my first car"?

新しい仕事をもらったから means "because I received a new job"; 辞めます means "I will quit" not "I will need to quit".

@A.Ellett 1) yes, That's exactly what I meant by 一台目の車 / 一つ目の車

@A.Ellett 2) by から I meant - after. After the verb, can't you add it like this? like - 見つけたから　- after i found?

No, that's grammatically incorrect for the intended meaning.

@Leebo so should i say smthing like 仕事がもらったら　- if i want to say 'after' in my example?

If you want to use から to mean "after", then it should follow the て-form of the verb.

@Leebo so 新しい仕事をもらってから、二日目に/二ヶ月めに/二週間目に　辞めます　- now its sound ok?


How do I use count 目 with days, months and years?

You can say 「２日目」「２週間目」「２ヶ月目」「２年目」.
Examples:

京都に来て２日目に清水寺に行きました。
アルバイトを始めて２カ月目に入りました。
引っ越してから２年目に町内会の役員が回ってきました。



"From the beginning of my employment on the second month/second day/second week I will need to quit my new job."

I think you can probably say:
「新しい仕事を始めてから２年目に辞めなければいけません。」
「新しい仕事を始めても、２年目の途中で辞めなければいけません。」
「新しい仕事を２年目に辞めないといけません。」
or more simply,
「新しい仕事を２日で辞めないといけません。」 which means "I will need to quit my new job in two days." (I think ２年で and ２年目に can be quite different, but ２日で and ２日目に are not so different... Does ２日目に辞める "quit on the 2nd day" mean you will not work on the 2nd day? ２日で辞める sounds to me like you work on the 1st and 2nd days.)
